# replace the year (4 digits) of the post_date field in wordpress WP_POSTS Table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-update

I want to mass replace the 4 digits year inside the field post_date in the wp_posts table.

Could someone show what the SQL statement should be execute?

I want to change from `2011-02-06 17:05:07` to `2012-02-06 17:05:07` , so only the year change from 2011 to 2012.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_date = DATE_ADD(post_date , INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
-- WHERE condition here
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79c35/1)

SOURCE

- [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)